# Google Apps Engine: Using later version of NumPy

Tags: google-app-engine, numpy

I'm trying to use the Pandas module through Google Apps Engine. It requires NumPy 1.7 or later. Unfortunately Google Apps Engine is stuck at 1.6.1. I've loaded several other third party modules in my libs folder, including Plotly (for which I am using Pandas) without a problem, but placing a later version of NumPy in my libs folder isn't working. So, anyone know a way to use a newer version of NumPy with Apps Engine?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the `libs` folder only supports pure python packages that don't have any C-extensions:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27#installing_a_library

Numpy has all sorts of C-extensions, so it looks like you may be stuck with the older version of numpy that Google App Engine supports. Pandas also doesn't look like a supported library and has C-extensions, so it seems like you can't use that either. From what I've read, you would have to use the Google App Engine Flexible Environment to install this class of packages.